# How can I make my phone/tablet ring remotely without a SIM card?

Tags: applications, security, lost-phone

I appear to have lost my Streak somewhere in my apartment, and I can't call it since I don't have a SIM card in it.  I've remotely installed [Plan B](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb) just because, but unfortunately the GPS coordinates are not specific enough to find it inside my apartment :P.  Is there any app I can install remotely that will start making noise so I can find the device?

Comment: Is it possible to remote-install apks? Also can the apps be started remotely? That way if there are no apps to be found, somebody could make one.

Comment: If account sync is on, you can try and create a calendar event with alarm on a desktop computer, and hope that your audio notifications are turned on.

Comment: @MartinTapankov That's interesting, I think calendar sync is off but I'll try it later.  varesa, I don't think so apart from the Market or having something like WiFi adb installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bahh! Just found a way to do this! I'm so excited!

First, install [AndroidLost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmFuZHJvaWRsb3N0Il0.) from the online Google Play Store.

- this is the app you can use to control/wipe/access info about your lost device, yadayada

Give it a little time to install to your device, then install [AndroidLost Jumpstart](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost.jumpstart&hl=en) from the online Google Play Store as well

> This app will wake up the registration process on the androidlost app
>   when ever a phone call is made, an SMS received, battery is low, a
>   package is added, removed or changed.

So you have to install an arbitrary app from the Play Store as well to activate the service, but you can then go to androidlost.com to access functions to control your lost device! *Including ringing an alarm ;)*

<strike>I haven't tested this yet, but I will as soon as I can</strike> I tested this on my own phone (although the page for Jumpstart only specifies tablets), and *it works*! It says it will register on SMS or app install, I did both first, and the activation worked. This is an **awesome** utility.

Comment: AndroidLost Jumpstart will not work on the newer versions of Android.

Answer (score 1):

*[Where's my Droid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.alienmanfc6.wheresmyandroid)* does that and is the best free app on the market:

Instructions:

> To use the app, text "wmd ring" to make the device ring

Taken from http://wheresmydroid.com/

EDIT:

I'm sorry, my answer above assumes you have some other way SIP or Google Voice to send an SMS, which you would have already had setup!

I'm not aware of any app that does this without initiation from an SMS. Sorry.

Comment: I just hope you don't run out of batteries first! That's always your enemy, at that point.

Comment: You're right about the batteries, if I lost my phone over night I'd have a 4-5 hour window in the morning to remotely find it!

Comment: Okay, well, I created an app that does this, but I wont be able to upload it to market until I hear back from Google.

Answer (score -1):

Where's My Droid can send a ring request from their website, or app on another device, once you are logged into your account.