# Find a stolen Android device without sim card

Tags: lost-phone

I'm looking for an app that could help me find/take pictures & record sound/ erase my data / block device if I lose my cell.

I don't know if is it possible, but will be really useful if the app can work even if there is no sim inside the device/ switched off or have GPS/internet connection disabled.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this question. Lots of useful answers there.
[link](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2492/13240)

Comment: I had asked a similar question to this one: [How can I make my phone/tablet ring remotely without a SIM card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18812/how-can-i-make-my-phone-tablet-ring-remotely-without-a-sim-card)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cerberus can be activated by both it's web service and via text message.  If you're rooted, it can be integrated into the system apps and so survive a complete wipe.  FYI, NO app will let you track your phone while it's turned off :)

It can also turn on the GPS remotely, has real time tracking using Google maps (looks like Google navigation in a web browser), take pics/record sound & video, sound an alarm, hide itself from the app drawer so thieves won't know it's there, remotely lock the phone with a code, wipe the system, display messages, download the last 10 texts and phone calls, and LOTS more.

Cerberus is $5, and worth every penny. It can be downloaded from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lsdroid.cerberus), but the download section on the official site has [Cerberus APKs that can be flashed and integrated directly into the ROM](https://www.cerberusapp.com/download.php).

Comment: It's not integrated into the kernel. A helper apk is moved to system/app.

Comment: Noted & corrected :)

Answer (score 3):

[AndroidLost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbmRyb2lkbG9zdCJd) is my personal favorite. I don't know if it can turn the device on, but I know it works for everything else. My favorite feature is the pop-up message you can send that takes a picture with the front facing camera when they click OK. If you don't have access to your phone, install it via the market link and login on their site!

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any anti-theft app that can be activated in any way besides sending a text message. What you can do, however, is installing one of these apps and immediately activating it before losing your phone. Having GPS continously activated may drain your battery more than you'd like to, though.

Of course, your phone can neither phone home nor be remote controlled unless it has some sort of internet connection. But Wifi should still work without a SIM card.

The most popular apps for this sort of thing seem to be [Prey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prey) and [Where's my Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alienmanfc6.wheresmyandroid). The latter requires the paid pro version if you need remote wipe.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Latitude](https://latitude.google.com/latitude/b/0) tracks your location — that would work until they wipe your phone, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the phone hasn't been wiped , and is logged into your account, and has *some* form of network access, [Android device manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) can locate, wipe and lock your phone. With newer versions you need to enable location access. I tested location and ringing on a phone with wifi, but no functional sim card (I have an old cancelled one inside to keep it from complaining).

Without *any* way to communicate with a phone its tricky. [Prey is pretty nice](https://preyproject.com/), has a proven track record (and a pretty [impressive recoveries page](https://preyproject.com/blog/cat/recoveries)) and can be activated over [text](http://support.preyproject.com/kb/common-questions-and-answers/how-do-i-run-prey-on-my-android-phone). It will also activate itself on a *sim card change* or removal, and try to call back so it may be useful since the phone will *have* to be turned on eventually to get any use of it.

Nothing can track a switched off phone, short of magic.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Android Device Manager, but your phones 3G must be online or it must be connected to WiFi

Comment: [Journeyman Geek's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/63341/12442) already mentioned that. In future, please take care to avoid repeating previous answers, which just wastes everyone's time.