# How to find my stolen galaxy ace duos

Tags: sim-card, lost-phone

I lost my galaxy ace duos. The sim card has been changed.  How can i trace phone or find the number of the new sim being used? I have several apps installed. can that help in anyway? Thanks for the help

Comment: Also possibly relevant: [Find a stolen Android device without sim card](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20472/find-a-stolen-android-device-without-sim-card)

Answer (score 1):

Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos has Android 2.3 installed, so you should be able to use [Plan B](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb&hl=en).

This app sends the location of your phone to your email. Of course this requires your phone having a connection to Google play with your account.

In general: saying 'I have several apps installed' does not help, providing information what apps are installed maybe does.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have installed Plan B. And I pray it will be successful.