# I lost my Android smartphone. Play Store tells me that someone has inserted a SIM card. How can I find out the phone number?

Tags: security, lost-phone

I lost my Samsung Galaxy S, which was signed into Google Play.
Now, Play Store has identified that someone has inserted another SIM card with a different service provider.
Is there anyway I can find out the phone number of the inserted SIM?

Comment: I think you need to install [Plan B](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb&hl=en). This will help you track it down.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18644/my-phone-was-just-stolen-an-hour-or-so-ago-are-there-any-options-for-tracking

Comment: @Sid You're wrong. Plan B doesn't require Mobile number just the Google account intact.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to see you losing your phone. Have you seen the question "[Can I remotely launch an app on my android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23640/can-i-remotely-launch-an-app-on-my-android-phone)" in which [@jlehenbauer](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/6052/jlehenbauer) has answered mentioning an app called [AndroidLost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmFuZHJvaWRsb3N0Il0.).  You can try this if you are sure you have your lost phone still uses your Google Account.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a stolen phone (theft of mislaid property). Report it to the police. In the US, if you have the esn/meid they can compel the carrier to give them all the info about who's using the phone.  I'm not sure how these things work in other countries.

Comment: If you don't have the IMEI you can probably get it from your carrier, just ask them for it.