# Lost my android tablet, how can I find it without a network connection?

Tags: acer-iconia-a500, lost-phone

I lost my tablet today. It's fully charged but it has no WiFi connection on. Is there any way I can find it without any connected network?

Comment: Possibly a dupe of [Find a stolen Android device without sim card](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20472) or [How can I make my phone/tablet ring remotely without a SIM card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18812) although those kind of assume you at least have some form of network connectivity. If it's completely offline you probably can't do anything (after all - how would you communicate with it to find it?)

Comment: Your tablet is definitely AWOL, no getting it back unless somewhat, report to your local law enforcement authorities and put out an alert, showing serial number and appeal to the public to watch out if its being sold elsewhere, other than that, no can do, and  anyway, if there's no connectivity, how would you be expected to communicate with it? Computers with telepathy/mind control is way off! Sorry its not what you wanted to hear!

Answer (score 1):

The only way is likely going to where you went today. It will be very diificult to find it without network connection. [Lookout Plan B](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb) would have helped you if your device had got something to manage SMS but it is a tablet.